# SweetAlert2 doesn't work on IE 11, Promise is not defined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, promise, sweetalert2

I'm using SweetAlert2 and on IE 11 throws exception:

> This package requires a Promise library, please include a shim to
>   enable it in this browser (See:
>   https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2#1-ie-support)

Because IE 11 doesn't support Promises and needs to be added manually.

I'm using bluebird like so:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const Swal = require('sweetalert2');

Swal.fire(...)
...
```

But still, sweetalert's check doesn't pass:

```
..
  if (typeof Promise === 'undefined') {
    error('This package requires a Promise library, please include a shim to enable it in this browser (See: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2#1-ie-support)');
  }
..
```

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@7.1.0/dist/promise.min.js"></script>` to your html.

Comment: I need to add it using require, and I've already added bluebird polyfill.

Comment: Why do you **need** to? The documentation you posted, literally says to add that script for IE.

Comment: Because I don't want to add additional resources to the page, I have 30+ pages/resources using sweetalert2, I need to go through every one of the htmls and add this.

Comment: Then put the javascript in a file and export it? This doesn't need to be difficult...

Comment: It doesn't work, and if you read my question carefully you should understand that `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@7.1.0/dist/promise.min.js` and bluebird are the same thing - polyfills which add Promises to unsupported browsers. But for some reason sweetalert2 doesn't recognise it, maybe the bluebird polyfill is not added in imported by request() libraries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191461/discussion-between-nacholibre-and-swonder).

Comment: Use `window.Promise = require('bluebird');`

Comment: @ChinLeung this fixed the problem, thanks, but how can I add in globally and should I? Or it's better to add window.Promise in every file I use SweetAlert2?

Comment: You can have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it with the following:

```
window.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

This will load Promise as a global variable of your window instead of the file like you did with the `const`.

I'm not sure how your file structure is, but if you have a file that loads all the dependencies, you can simply add the line above to the script that will be called before your other scripts.

For example:

```
// bootstrap.js
window.Promise = require('bluebird');
window.Swal = require('sweetalert2');

// app.js
require('./bootstrap');
Swal.fire(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using Sweetalert2 directly by referencing it in pages:

This could also be fixed by including the below core js lib after Sweetalert2 lib

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.js"></script>
```